# PDO bind loop index

Tags: php, pdo

I have some user uploaded images that can be sorted and need to save the image position. Was thinking that I could do this easy enough by just using the loop index while iterating through them. However using my $i variable to bind the 3rd param is being passed as a reference and I need the value. How do I get around this?

Here's the code:

```
$postId = $args['postId'];
$images = explode(",", $args['images']);

$sql = 'INSERT INTO post_image (name,postId,ordinal) VALUES ';
$part = array_fill(0, count($images), "(?, ?, ?)");
$sql .= implode(",", $part);
logit($sql);

try{
  $db = DB::getInstance();
  $stmt = $db->dbh->prepare($sql);
  $count = count($images);
  $n = 1;
  for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
    $stmt->bindParam($n++, $images[$i]);
    $stmt->bindParam($n++, $postId);
    $stmt->bindParam($n++, $i);
  }
  $result = $stmt->execute();

  if($result !== false) {
    return true;
  }else {
    logit('Query Failed');
    return false;
  }
}catch(PDOException $e) {
   logit($e->getMessage());
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using bindValue for the third param.